# How to select required application into BI Application Archive (BAR) file. OBIEE 12C

Tags: obiee

I am in the course of developing a script to generate .bar file with a set required applications metadata from the development server using wlst. BI Application Archive is the exact match for this requirement as this outputs a .bar file which can be added into the build and later be imported into any other environments.

As I understood, BI Application Archive adds all the applications in the instance into the .bar file. Development server may have test or under development reports which need not be part of the archive. I am wondering how to generate .bar file with only the required applications.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking -perhaps inadvertently- about the idea of pluggable BI. This has been on Oracle's roadmap slides for a year or so now, the idea being that you can take just a "HR" 'application' and deploy it alongside other 'applications'.
So far as I'm aware, it is only that though -- slideware.

For the here and now, OBIEE 12.2.1, you can only work with BAR files at the grain of the entire service instance, i.e. the complete RPD/Catalog/Security model. You use WLST export/importServiceInstance commands to work with these bar files.

You may find this useful:

- https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/12/source-control-and-automated-code-deployment-options-for-obiee/
- https://speakerdeck.com/rmoff/source-control-code-deployment-and-concurrent-development-for-obiee-12c